# Can't Deploy Java Application to App Engine Standard

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I have a Google Cloud Endpoints Java application that I am developing for App Engine Standard. I am unable to deploy it locally from Eclipse but I can deploy and run it locally like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
mvn clean package endpoints-framework:openApiDocs -DskipTests \
&& gcloud endpoints services deploy target/openapi-docs/openapi.json \
&& clear \
&& mvn appengine:run -Dapp.devserver.host=0.0.0.0 | tee appengine.out
```

Now I want to deploy it to App Engine Standard.  If I try to deploy it using the Eclipse plugin I get:

```
Reading application configuration data...
2021-01-16 11:56:14.946:INFO::main: Logging initialized @370ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
Bad configuration: Missing required element 'application'.
Please see the logs [/tmp/appcfg1077472932380362760.log] for further information.
```

The log file says:

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Missing required element 'application'.
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml.getApplication(AppYaml.java:804)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml.generateAppEngineWebXml(AppYaml.java:1296)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYamlProcessor.convert(AppYamlProcessor.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.<init>(Application.java:250)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.readApplication(Application.java:536)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readWar(AppCfg.java:303)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readApplication(AppCfg.java:281)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:209)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:118)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:114)
```

If I try to deploy it from the command line I get:

```
$ gcloud app deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Maven source deployment is not supported for Java8 GAE project.
```

When I run:

```
gcloud config list
```

I get what looks like the correct value for "project".

Is there a way to deploy this application to App Engine Standard?

Thanks for your help.

-Dan

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-maven), this way of deployment is now deprecated. Have you tried the method mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-maven#migrating_to_the_new_plugin) for this?

Comment: Thanks rsalinas.  Your suggestion led me to a solution.  -Dan